# Firebase CLI appdistribution:distribute issue : nothing appens, no upload, no error

Tags: android, firebase, mobile-application, firebase-cli, firebase-app-distribution

I'm currently trying to deploy apk to firebase apps distribution but we have a issue.

the command

`````
firebase appdistribution:distribute appqualityrelease.apk –app xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ````
`````

don't produce any output, it juste exit.

I'm correctly logged in using cli, app id is correct, apk is valid (it runs on simulator and physical device)
I also tried to use this command on our CI/CD environment (Azure Devops) with CI token,

All attempt produce the same issue : the command exit without error on the console (on DevOps, the message is Bash exited with code 1)
On Devops, we also try to run the deploy on Windows, Ubuntu, MacOs : same issue.

I also added the debug flag and there is only one error

```
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.894Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.896Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase appdistribution:distribute appqualityrelease.apk –app xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --debug
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.897Z] CLI Version:   11.20.0
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.897Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.897Z] Node Version:  v16.17.1
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.898Z] Time:          Fri Jan 13 2023 08:55:33 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
[debug] [2023-01-13T07:55:33.899Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[error] 
[error] Error: Too many arguments. Run firebase help appdistribution:distribute for usage instructions
```

Could someone help us?

Answer (score 0):

your argument is wrong on `-app`, it should be `--app`

based on your command
`firebase appdistribution:distribute appqualityrelease.apk -–app xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `````

**updated:**

from my opinion firebase cli is a little bad, i have my experience also when i'm using flag `--release-notes` but i got typo `-- release-notes`. same like you, no error/warning and just silently fail